# how can i pass object to jquery dialog?

Tags: object, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to pass object to jQuery dialog.

code;

```
 var arr = new Array(ResultList.length);
     for(var i=0; i<ResultList.length;i++){
         arr[i] = ResultList[i];
     }

 $.ajax({
    url: 'plz.do',
    type: 'POST',
    data:
        {
            "Comment" : comment,
            "Index" : index,
        },
        success:function(data) {
             ..........
        }
    });
```

ResultList

```
ResultList = [{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}....]
```

This code can pass variable to jQuery dialog but I failed to pass object to jQuery dialog.

Comment: i tryed data:{"arr" : arr} but failed.

Comment: also i tryed data{"arr": arr.serialize()}